# CentOS: AJAX/jQuery not working

Tags: ajax, jquery

In a nutshell, I have an unmanaged VPS. At one time, it had Ubuntu 10.10 server on it, then I reinstalled it with CentOS 6 and updated it to CentOS 6.2. Now, the problem is, the AJAX/jQuery shoutbox has ceased working (I assume it uses one of the two to inject itself into a div and then refresh when new messages are posted, I'm not sure, I didn't write these), and the plug-board script now shows me a lime green blank page. **No changes** to the source codes have been made, and they are in the location they expect themselves to be.

I have Apache2, MySQL 5, PHP 5, and I did install the php-xml libraries. What am I missing? It's gotta be server side because the scripts themselves are fine, if I move them to a different server they work just fine. I'm not getting any errors related to this in the error_log file. Thanks in advance!

*Edit:* If you want, you can look at the plugboard at kazeshini.net/plugboard and there's an installation of the chatbox at silverlotus.kazeshini.net/yshout/example, I know nothing about scripts and debugging so better someone else looks at it than someone that doesn't know what they're looking for.

Comment: What does your JavaScript error log say?

Comment: How do I get to it? I was not aware there was one for JS >>;

Comment: Depends on your browser.

Comment: Well, I'm using Chrome so I got into its debugger and there's nothing in there about the scripts, just unrelated missing files (which is my fault anyway).

Comment: You should be able to use the debugger to inspect the AJAX network requests and see what's going on there. It's difficult to help you more without an example link.

Comment: Added a couple links to the scripts I'm talking about; I have no idea what I should be looking for lol They should be fine themselves though it makes no sense for something to be wrong with the scripts themselves when they work fine, as they are, elsewhere. :/

Comment: On the server that works, what php packages are installed and what version? Same for the Centos server that doesn't work?

Comment: I couldn't tell you the packages for the one that works, I'm not admin on it. I can tell you the CentOS server has php-5.3.3, php-common-5.3.3, php-cli-5.3.3, php-pdo-5.3.3, php-xml-5.3.3, php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5... php-pear-1.9.4, php-gd-5.3.3, php-mysql-5.3.3 and that's all the PHP packages I can find.

Comment: It's not the scripts, it's your particular installation. It'd be best if we could see it so we can poke at it.

Answer (score 1):

In short, it looks like your PHP install is busted or configured incorrectly and is not parsing the page properly. Looking at the source of your page, I see the following:

```
<? include "config.php"; ?>

<? include "plug.php"; ?>
```

PHP should be parsing these and doing its thing. You need to make sure the PHP module is being loaded into Apache properly and is parsing the correct `php.ini` file.

Create a file with the following contents to verify if PHP is being loaded. If it is, you should get a load of information about your PHP install.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

If PHP is definitely being loaded, then it's short tags that's the problem. Either enable short tags in the `php.ini` file or change your `<?` to `<?php`.

Comment: What was it, short tags?

Comment: Yeah. I knew PHP was being loaded because I had no issues with running a forum installation so. Both of the scripts were written with short tags and I wasn't gonna run through a zillion files changing em so I just enabled short tags. *nod* =3 Thanks again!